# Using ranges for lists or arrays in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, range

I have tried and I failed. Which cases that "ranges" used for?

> var list = listOf(1,2,3,4,5)

It's worked well. But following code didn't work as I wanted. Why?

> var list = listOf(1 .. 5)

Runnable program is : https://pl.kotl.in/c5256MZEC.

Answer (score 22):

That syntax creates a list of ranges (`List<IntRange>`) with a single range in it. You can convert a range (or any Iterable) to a List with `toList()`:

```
(1..5).toList()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have points I didn't understand. 1- When IntRange is used. And why we can not use IntRange in listOf while it is used in for loop? It might be a little bit weird question. I think it is about process of building of this language.  2- Why output was "1 .. 5"? I mean why output is like string. 3- I see the data type as ArrayList. But I defined(var list2:ArrayList) this type manually and it gives error. Automatically doesn't give error.

Comment: You can use IntRange in listOf, but you will get a list of IntRanges.
You could also do `listOf((1..4), (1..6), (1..22))`.

Comment: 1. Because `1..5` is a function call that returns an IntRange. `listOf()` makes a list of whatever arguments you give it, in this case a List of IntRanges.

Comment: 2. You have a list of IntRanges. Your for-loop is logging each item in the list, but you only have one range in your list. `IntRange.toString()` prints the representation of the range in this format, like `"$first..$last"`. You can see it in the source code: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/8852323a76eb6f528f361a9415f9df422489a1ee/core/builtins/src/kotlin/Ranges.kt#L54

Comment: 3. `toList()` returns a `List`. You can instead use `toMutableList()` to create a `MutableList` if that's what you need. In Kotlin, `MutableList` should be used instead of `ArrayList`, usually. If you really need `ArrayList`, you could use `ArrayList((1..5).toList())`

Comment: Thanks for answers I got it. @Tenfour04 for 3. question. I get output by `println(list2::class.simpleName)`. Output is `ArrayList`. But I put data type manually it gives error `var list2: ArrayList = 1.rangeTo(5).toList()`

Comment: `toList()` returns a List. `toMutableList()` returns a MutableList. If you want the more specific type ArrayList, you have to use the ArrayList constructor like I said. `ArrayList((1..5).toList())` But ArrayList is usually avoided in Kotlin. That's why there is no `toArrayList()`. You can cast your `List` to an `ArrayList` by using `(1..5).toList() as ArrayList`, but it is not guaranteed to be safe. Not all Lists are ArrayLists, even in the Kotlin standard library.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't understand. Perhaps I couldn't explain well. What I'm trying to say: https://pl.kotl.in/OLppzxGMl

Comment: ArrayList is the underlying type that you can inspect using reflection with `::class`, but it is not the type that is known to the compiler because it has been cast to the supertype `List` before you receive it in your funciton. The safe convention is to use the type it has been cast to. Reflection can get you in trouble because you are circumventing the intent of the author of the function you are calling. The designers of Kotlin can theoretically change the underlying type to some other List implementation that is not an ArrayList and then if your code casts it, it will crash in the future.

Comment: For example, usually when a function returns a List, it means you are not supposed to modify its contents, even if you can check with reflection and see that it is actually a MutableList.

Answer (score 3):

You can also iterate through it without having to convert it to a list

```
var list2 = 1..5
list2.forEach {
    println(it) 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option (same as @Tenfour04 response but more readable) is to use the `rangeTo` operator and convert it to a list with the same extension function `toList`:

```
val list = 1.rangeTo(5).toList()
```

Comment: I don't consider it as more readable, but if you are going to use `rangeTo`, you don't need the extra parentheses. `1.rangeTo(5).toList()`